# How to update existing specific node in graphdb by loading updated CSV file in neo4J apoc

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc, load-csv

I am facing problem updating node  by loading recently updated csv file in. neo4j. since it is a large file I think apoc procedure is need to be used. I  have updated existing node  by loading external updated file without apoc. but problem is I need to update it in parallel using apoc. here is my file element

original element in file

```
ID,SHOPNAME,DIVISION,DISTRICT,THANA
1795,ARAFAT DISTRIBUTION,RAJSHAHI,JOYPURHAT,Panchbibi
1796,CONNECT DISTRIBUTION,DHAKA,GAZIPUR,Gazipur Sadar
1797,HUMAYUN KABIR,DHAKA,DHAKA,Demra
```

I have  created node from this CSV

then I have another updated file  u.csv  the updated elements are given bellow

```
ID,SHOPNAME,DIVISION,DISTRICT,THANA
1795,ABC,RAJSHAHI,JOYPURHAT,Panchbibi
1796,XYZ,DHAKA,GAZIPUR,Gazipur Sadar
1797,HUMAYUN KABIR,DHAKA,DHAKA,Demra
```

without apoc  my  query was

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///u.csv" AS line
MERGE (c:Agent {ID:line[0]})
ON MATCH SET c.SHOPNAME = line[1]
RETURN c
```

This code  updated desired column except  I have got a blank node

```
{"ID":"ID"}
```

**my first question is why  a new blank node is created** and how could I solve this

Now I am wanting it for updating large file  so I have used to apoc procedure for batch processing

with apoc my query was

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate('LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///u.csv" AS line return line','MERGE (p:Agent{ID:TOINTEGER(line.ID)}) ON MATCH SET p.SHOPNAME=TOINTEGER(line.SHOPNAME) ' ,{batchSize:10000, iterateList:true, parallel:true});
```

but I could not updated the specific nodes  rather it created two nodes  with related id so  I am getting 5 nodes  here rather than 3 nodes

```
{"ID":1795} 
{"ID":1796}
```

I am very new to neo4j but trying to learn.  kindly help me to solve the problem 
  I am using  neo4j 3.5.6 and apoc 3.5.0.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I see 2-3 possible issues here:**

- **Regarding Duplicate Nodes**: You used `TOINTEGER` function in one and not in another data load query, so nodes are duplicated. One `Agent` node with `id` with the data type string and other `Agent` node with `id` with the data type integer.

> **Suggestion:** Use `TOINTEGER` function in both queries or none.

- **Regarding Blank Nodes:** 
  In your second query, you are setting node property only if node found(i.e. `ON MATCH`).
  But as per the first case, we have found it's creating a new node every time and not matching any of the previous node. Also not setting property when creating. So there will nodes with no **SHOPNAME**.

> **Suggestion:** Either Add `ON CREATE` to `MERGE` query or remove `ON MATCH` from MERGE query and update node every time. Adding  `ON
>   CREATE`  is a recommended and efficient way.

**Please find below query with `ON CREATE`:**

```
MERGE (c:Agent {ID:line[0]})
ON CREATE SET 
    c.SHOPNAME = line[1]
```

- You are also converting `SHOPNAME` to integer in your query with APOC using `TOINTEGER`, this will not work.

Comment: ,one extra thing needs to know regarding this topic.  Is there any query to update all fields from an updated CSV.  like here I am updating the only shop name.  but what if I want to update all of the fields like division, district, thana column. Or do i need  it to update  one by one